# How can I implement 'login with aws' for a web application?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, amazon-iam

We are building a web application that asks users to login using their aws account and uses the auth token generated to access specific resources from the user's aws account.

This is similar to the support in Azure and GCP:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-register-app

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in

What is the correct way of implementing this for aws?

**Investigation done so far:**

**Aws Cognito** - We explored aws cognito and it seems like it is a solution to manage our own user pool. Users will need to sign up and signed-in users can sign in. We are looking to access the aws user pool, instead of managing our own user pool.

**Aws STS** - STS has APIs to generate temp credentials for an IAM role, but the STS SDK itself needs to be initialized using our aws credentials. So this scenario is not feasible for web applications.

We are looking for a way which uses the oAuth2 protocol to authenticate the user and return an access token to the web application.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure those Microsoft and Google examples you linked actually give you access to the user's Azure or GCP cloud computing infrastructure? I think it just authenticates the user and gives you their authenticated email address, not the keys to their infrastructure. I've used both of those before, and it's similar to the Cognito [Login With Amazon](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon.html) feature, which is also just going to authenticate the user and give you the email address associated with their Amazon account.

What I have seen done in the past for applications that need access to your AWS account, is for that application to publish an IAM policy example (with only the permissions required by the service), and instructions for creating an IAM user with that specific policy, and generating access keys for that user. Then the application takes those access keys as input, and uses them to perform actions against the AWS account.

Comment: For Microsoft and Google, I have the option to request access for specific scopes(like Azure.Subscripiton.Read, GoogleCloud.Container.Create) when asking the user to sign-in. The resulting auth token can be used to call cloud provider specific APIs.

I believe, existing aws IAM users cannot login using Amazon since aws IAM and Amazon do not share a common identity provider. So, the login with Amazon path won't work.

Comment: Got it. As far as I know there is nothing like that for AWS.